# How to create `ExpressionType.Increment

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression

How can I create a Linq expression that will generate an ExpressionType.Increment?

Tried the following:

```
var q = query.Select(x => (x + 1));
var q = query.Select(x => x + 1);
var q = query.Select(x => localIntVariable + 1);
```

but all of them return an `Expression.Add`

### Official Description

A unary increment operation, such as (a + 1) in C# and Visual Basic.

The object a should not be modified in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BCL support for expression trees is greater than the C# support. Several expression node types are available that exist in C#, but the C# compiler does not allow in expression trees. In this particular case even, `ExpressionType.Increment` represents an operation which does not exist in stand-alone form in C# at all.

So, there is no way in C# to have the compiler generate `ExpressionType.Increment`. Other languages might, but I don't know of any. If you want to experiment with this operation, you need to build an expression tree manually.

Comment: Thanks, thought as much, as there are a lot of these expresisons types that do not get compiled! It's safe to say I won't be needing to implement them at this moment then!

Comment: Although the following is a little misleading: `A unary increment operation, such as (a + 1) in C# and Visual Basic`

Comment: @MichalCiechan Indeed. `a + 1` is an addition, not an increment, but that addition would give the same result as an increment.

Comment: It is indeed very misleading, since the `+` in `(a + 1)` is a binary operator. Pascal has a `Succ` function which returns next element of an ordinal type without modifying the original value. This would be a candidate for this expression type `Increment`.

Comment: @hvd to be honest, the expressiong should probably not be called `Increment` as the spec specifically says `The object a should not be modified in place.` Where as, Post/PreIncrement 's are `in-place`

Comment: @MichalCiechan For custom types with an overloaded `operator++`, that method was already called `op_Increment` and also does not modify the object in-place. `Increment` would call `op_Increment`. The name may be misleading at first glance but it is consistent with the rest of .NET.